# Browser not responding while knockout.js templates are generated

Tags: knockout.js

I would like my browser to be accessible immediately without having to wait for a template being loaded. Currently this is not the case when I'm providing a large array (in this case 1000 elements).
I've tried using an [External Template Engine](https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine), but this just results in the templates displaying "Loading ...", and the browser is not responding until they have finished loading.

To illustrate, a short example:

JS:

```
function User(firstname, lastname) {
    this.firstname = ko.observable(firstname);
    this.lastname = ko.observable(lastname);
}

function UserViewModel() {
    this.allUsers = ko.observableArray([
        new User("John", "Doe"),
        new User("John", "Doe"),
        new User("John", "Doe"),
        // 1000 elements ...
        new User("John", "Doe")
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new UserViewModel());
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>

    <body>

        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', foreach: allUsers() }"></ul>

        <script type="text/html" id="my-template">
            <li>
                <h1 data-bind="text: firstname()"></h1>
                <h2 data-bind="text: lastname()"></h2>
            </li>
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

So basically what I would like is the browser to be accessible when the templates are rendering, and as soon as they are ready they should be visualized. The External Template Engine which I mentioned earlier does not meet my needs.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try this approach:

[Show progress bar while knockout is rendering the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227704/show-progress-bar-while-knockout-is-rendering-the-view)

If you take a look at the linked jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/fdSUU/) you will see the approach being used.

You basically start off with your data in a seperate array and then load them into the array say 50 items at a time via a `setTimeout` call. This keeps the browser active while the data loads.

Comment: Thanks. With 'regular' data, this is indeed working, but when I use custom objects (e.g. the User object from the topic post), this is still not working as it should (probably because of the ko.observable() attached to it).

Comment: Yes you are right. I made the mistake of setting the numToPush variable to the initial array length, but after reviewing the code this is obviously not the right way to do. Do you think 10 is the best option here, or could I also change this to for example 1?

Comment: Yes you can change the 10. Maybe change it to a number that matches the number of items it takes to fill the screen. Then the user will get visual feedback ASAP and then the page can get on with rendering the rest of its contents. If you change it to 1 this would work but *may* affect page performance.